# COMCTL Common Controls Progressbar displays ugly blue bars

Tags: vb6, progress-bar

I have a VB6 program which uses comctrl32.ocx to display a progress bar.  I've also had programs using mscomctl.ocx.  However, it is displaying it using the ugly, old-style blue boxes progress bar instead of using the new-style progressbar (which presumably varies depending on the OS).  Other programs which reference that same ocx file display the new-style progressbar (unless I run them VB6, in which case they still use the ugly one).  All of the properties of the control are the same.  Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your application doesn't have a manifest and therefore uses the old pre-Windows XP style common controls. vbAccelerator has a [great article on how to add one](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/code/libraries/XP_Visual_Styles/Using_XP_Visual_Styles_in_VB/article.asp)

Comment: There were a lot of annoying problems causing this issue, but the focal point was the manifest.  Many thanks.